# Run code only between start and end time

Tags: android

I'd like to be able to set the times for my service to execute some of its code. It runs via AlarmManager regularly, and when it's running, I'd like to have it execute some code only if the time is between a window, say between 10am and 2pm (or 10 and 14).

I have created a `TimePickerDialog` that starts from `OnClick` of two `Buttons`, "Start Time" and "End Time". Looking at the "Start Time" case, the code follows:

TimePickerDialog code:

```
public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
Calendar dateTimeStart = Calendar.getInstance();

new TimePickerDialog(this, t, dateTimeStart.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), dateTimeStart.get(Calendar.MINUTE), DateFormat.is24HourFormat(this)).show();
}

TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener t = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                startTime = new Time();
                startTime.hour = hourOfDay;
                startTime.minute = minute;
                startButton.setText(new StringBuilder().append(startTime));
}
```

The `setText` method lets me see what kind of data I'm working with - it's a `Time` format that has an output like `19700101T100000America/Toronto(0,0,,-1,54000)`

I had been using the `Calendar` class instead of the `Time` class and it was more robust.

So I know it's setting the time after the `T`, but I'm having trouble getting a human readable `10:00` out of it to display to the user, as well as using the time set as a point for running code.

1. How to format the user-inputted time (ie 10:00) for comparison with current time?
2. How to compare the properly formatted times?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used was the use the integers from the `TimePickerDialog`, `hourOfDay` and `minute`.

Since they were integers, it was simple to compare them with other integers of hour and minute from the current time that was found via:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(New Date());
int hour = calender.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

That's the easiest way of dealing with times, in my opinion.